# for loop not returning any values

Tags: postgresql

```
do
$$
declare
    f record;
begin
    for f in SELECT DISTINCT station_code FROM rainfall LIMIT 3
    loop
    EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM rainfall WHERE station_code=''%I''', f.station_code);
    RAISE NOTICE '%',f.station_code;
    end loop;
end;
$$
```

Hi i'm trying to print out the execute statement for each f.station_code. It doesn't return any output but doesn't throw error. The raise notice however returns

```
NOTICE:  MALUDAM
NOTICE:  IGAN
NOTICE:  LUBOKANTU
DO

Query returned successfully in 4 secs 4 msec.
```

Appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 0):

A `do` block can not return a result.

But I don't see any reason to use PL/pgSQL, a loop or even dynamic SQL for this:

A single query like the following will do what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM rainfall 
WHERE station_code IN (SELECT station_code FROM rainfall LIMIT 3);
```

(The IN with a LIMIT on the same table makes zero sense to me though)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I actually wanted to add a COUNT and GROUP BY in the query in EXECUTE but I used a more generic query for debugging because I couldn't get f.station_code to stick in %I. I understand that a nested loop can be used, but I would appreciate if you could help guide me as to how I could get the for loop case to work as I find it more intuitive than nested queries. Thanks.

Comment: @SidiqMK: again: a `do` block can **not** return a result. So what you are trying to achieve is not possible. And a PL/pgSQL for loop is the most inefficient way to do this. The sub-select is way more efficient and will scale a lot better.

Comment: @SidiqMK A for loop is very rarely needed in SQL and should be considered a last resort.  You will be far better served by learning how to write queries involving sets of data.